# Back and forward buttons not rendering templates in ember rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I always have this issue in ember apps that are built on a rails backend. I have a groups.hbs template which lists out a bunch of groups, when you click on a group it loads the group.hbs template next to the groups template and changes the url to /groups/:group_id.

However, when I click the back and forward buttons, or try to manually load a url with a specific :group_id the group template fails to render and the console throws a giant

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
  ...
```

error.

**group.js.coffee**

```
App.Group = Ember.Object.extend()

App.Group.reopenClass
  all: ->
    App.ajax(
      url: App.apiUrl('/groups')
    ).then (data) ->
      console.log data
      groups = []
      for group in data.response
        groups.addObject(App.Group.create(group))
      console.log(groups)
      groups
```

**router.js.coffee**

```
Mdm.Router.map ->
  @resource 'groups', ->
    @resource 'group', {path: "/:group_id"}

Mdm.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'
```

I've never experienced this issue when building standalone ember apps. Any idea what would cause this?

**EDIT**

I should add that I am pulling my data from an api via XHR requests.

**EDIT 2**

I just explicitly created the GroupRoute and had it load all of the groups, this code is identical to the GroupsRoute. The template is still not rendering, but I no longer get that error.

GroupRoute

```
App.GroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  App.Group.all()
)
```

And GroupsRoute:

```
App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  App.Group.all()
)
```

**EDIT 3**

Here's the whole error if it helps anyone.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
    var m = meta(this);
    m.proto = this;
    if (initMixins) {
  // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
  var mixins = initMixins;
  initMixins = null;
  this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
}
if (initProperties) {
  // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
  var props = initProperties;
  initProperties = null;

  var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

  for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
    var properties = props[i];

    Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

    for (var keyName in properties) {
      if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

      var value = properties[keyName],
          IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

      if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
        var bindings = m.bindings;
        if (!bindings) {
          bindings = m.bindings = {};
        } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
          bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
        }
        bindings[keyName] = value;
      }

      var desc = m.descs[keyName];

      Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
      Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));

      if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
        var baseValue = this[keyName];

        if (baseValue) {
          if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
            value = baseValue.concat(value);
          } else {
            value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
          }
        } else {
          value = Ember.makeArray(value);
        }
      }

      if (desc) {
        desc.set(this, keyName, value);
      } else {
        if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
          this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
        } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
          Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
        } else {
          this[keyName] = value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
finishPartial(this, m);
delete m.proto;
finishChains(this);
this.init.apply(this, arguments);
  } has no method 'find'
```

**EDIT**

So I think I figured out the problem, when you click the back button or enter a manual url it wasn't finding the obkect based on id. So I added a find() method to the Group model. Not it looks like this:

```
Mdm.Group = Ember.Object.extend()

Mdm.Group.reopenClass
  all: ->
    Mdm.ajax(
      url: Mdm.apiUrl('/groups')
    ).then (data) ->
      console.log data
      groups = []
      for group in data.response
        groups.addObject(Mdm.Group.create(group))
      console.log(groups)
      groups

  find: (group_id) ->
    Mdm.ajax(
      url: Mdm.apiUrl("/groups/#{group_id}")
    ).then (data) ->
      renderTemplate: (data)
```

And my GroupRoute looks like this:

```
Mdm.GroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    console.log 'oh hai'
    Mdm.Group.find(params.group_id)
```

Now in the console when I click the back button it is loading the data but its not associating the group template with the group_id. What is the best practice way to tell ember to do this?

Comment: I feel like its an issue with ember retrieving the objects from the api. When I use static fixture data in a standalone ember app with the same code everything works fine. But I don't understand how clicking the link to pull in the individual link is any different than changing the url another way, either by the back button or manually typing it.

Comment: There is a lot here. I would be happy to help debug if you can reproduce this in a jsfiddle. I'm pretty confident it has nothing to do with there being a rails backend or not.

Comment: Unfortunately that's difficult to do since I'm pulling the data from another rails api app that requires an oauth authentication token. There's really no way for me to replicate the data retrieval.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reproduce this in a throw-away app and share on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rails developer but try doing something like this for the simple model/route setup you show above

```
App.Group = Ember.Object.extend().reopenClass
  groups: []
  find: ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/api/groups/"
      type: "GET"
      cache: false
      dataType: "json"
      beforeSend: =>
        @groups.clear()
      success: (results) =>
        [@groups.addObject(App.Group.create(result)) for result in results]
      error: =>
        alert "error: failed to load the available groups"
    @groups

App.Router.map ->
  @resource "groups", path: "/", ->
    @route "group", path: "/:group_id"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Toran. I tried implementing that model and I essentially get the same giant error when trying to load the data initially, only this one has "has no method 'all'" at the end, instead of 'find'. Which comes from the method called in groups_route.js.coffee. Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: Toran, when I change 'App.Group.all()' in groups_route to 'App.Group.find()', the template renders but I get the error message, failed to load available groups.

Comment: so your network issue is broken via $.ajax -are you using the correct url?

Comment: I'm much closer, I added a section to my original question. I had to add find methods to the group route and model, but I still need the group template to render.

Comment: can you throw together a jsfiddle or jsbin with your full example? I'm not sure if you have a template for groups and group (also it would be good to see the full setup to help debug the issue)

Comment: I do have a template for groups and group. group loads inside groups. But when you hit the back button, etc, the group template doesn't refresh. I'll try and get a fiddle together. Thanks again.